# Binding Multiples Keys for the same action

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, keyboard

So, lately in an attempt to B-Hop(Bunny Hop), I have bound my jump to my Mousewheel, but I still find myself trying to use Space to jump from habit, can I bind two different buttons to do the same action?

Comment: I'm so sure you can through the console / .cfg (speaking from Counter-Strike: Source) but can't answer for certain! You _should_ be fine to do `bind space +jump` and `bind mwheelup +jump` (not 100% certain if that's mouse wheel up, but you get my gist) through your console or .cfg file, but you probably can't do it from the actual settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type these in the console and hit enter on every new line:

```
    bind MWHEELUP +jump - Might not want to bind on scroll up though (hit Enter)
    bind MWHEELDOWN +jump (hit Enter)
    bind space +jump (hit Enter)
```

I'm used to jump with scroll, but do go for space every once and a while when it's easier so both the button and the scroll jump.

If console is not active --> http://diaryofdennis.com/2015/09/19/how-to-activate-and-open-the-console-in-counter-strike-global-offensive/